# compare 2 subgraph with Hamming distances in R

Tags: r, igraph, hamming-distance, sna

I created a graph (igraph) from interview data. I would like to compare the sub-graphs of each interview to have a relative distance from each one.
I found that I could use Hamming's distance. There are a lot of packages that offer functions to calculate distance. But I can't figure out how to calculate the distance between each sub-graph.

As an exemple :

```
library(igraph)
g1 <- graph_from_literal(1-2-3-4-1, 2-5-4, 1-5)
V(g1)$interview <- 1
g2 <- graph_from_literal(6-7-9,8-4-2-10,1-10-9)
V(g2)$interview <- 2
big.g <- g1 + g2
set.seed(1234)
plot(big.g)
```

I would like to know how far `g1` (from interview 1) is to `g2`. A kind of similarity or dissimilarity index. The Hamming distances seems to be a way but I don't know how to deal with ...

Comment: Can you give us a little mock-up to demonstrate your problem in a reproducible way?

Comment: @AllanCameron regarding the exemple, I tried to use `sna::hdist()` but I need to have the same dimension for `g1` and `g2` .  this is rarely the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have find a solution from [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2008-04/msg00017.html)

```
int <- graph.intersection(g1,g2)
n.dist <- ecount(g1)+ecount(g2)-2*ecount(int)
n.dist

##14  <- result
```